# Quicken my simple sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

```
select count(*) from user 
 where userid not in (select userid from ship where status in ('1','0')) 
   and field='web';
```

This simple statement seems to be running a terribly long time, how do I change the sql so that it can run faster? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think any changes to the query would help, but indexes on userid and field would.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info and edit your question to include `explain analyze`, etc. Also, it can be best to avoid `NOT IN`; instead try `NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE ...)`

Answer (score 1):

It's best to avoid IN/NOT IN when dealing with large amounts of data. Assuming your userid columns are indexed, something like this may be faster:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u.userid)
    FROM user u
    LEFT JOIN ship s ON u.userid=s.userid AND s.status IN ('1', '0')
WHERE s.userid IS NULL AND field='web'
```